# How to enable make command in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've downloaded VSCode and installed a Verilog extensions.
Reading VsCode manual there should be a build in Make command.

First I created some verilog files.

Then I created a MakeFile with a compile command for the verilog command.

From the Terminal window I write:

> Make

The only response I get is something similar like this "Make not recognized"

Am I missing some steps here ?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a lowercase `make`?

Comment: Tried both,, no one works.

Comment: I have another computer with a VsCode installation,,, everything works on that computer ??????????